# How can I create a separate client.js file with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, client-server

How should the chat application example (described on https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) look if I wanted the client script that currently exists in the index.html file, to exist in a separate client.js file? *Note: In this example tutorial, I'm at the part where I'm trying to get `a user connected` to appear when refreshing the web page, but this is not working correctly.*

I've tried including `<script src="client.js"></script>` in the head section of my index.html file, and then

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io();
```

in my client.js file, but it does not work. When I run `node server.js`, the chat application design displays on the web page correctly, and I show the `listening on *:3000` text in the terminal, but **not** the `a user connected` text which should appear when I refresh the web page.

My `server.js`, `index.html`, and `client.js` files are all in the top level of the directory, and are as follows:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); // Based on some research, I feel that the problem might
                                           // be here, where I'm sending just a file, not a directory?..
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chat Application</title>
        <style>
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
            body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
            form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
            form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: 0.5%; }
            form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
            #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
            #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
          </style>
          <script src="client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
          <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**client.js**

```
// I am also unsure if the following is correct...
const io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io();
```

Comment: I think you forgot this step: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO
You are not included **socket.io.js** yet

Comment: I’m confused what you are referring to.. How do I include socket.io.js?

Comment: In **Integrating Socket.IO** part, you will see 2 parts:
1. A server that integrates with (or mounts on) the Node.JS HTTP Server socket.io.
**2. A client library that loads on the browser side socket.io-client.**
That means you will need socket.io library for client because client browser will not understand what socket io is?

Comment: So you will need include socket.io-client for the client which would be included in index.html file.
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>`

Comment: Are you webpacking/browserifying or any other alternative, your client.js code. If not then require won't work, you need to do what the above comment said to do and then simply write var socket = io().

Comment: Okay so let me get this straight (and please correct me where I'm wrong). There is server code which uses the Server API (which I would use in my server.js file) and then there's the client code which uses the Client API or socket-client.io (which I can use in my client.js file

Comment: If I include what @HVD suggested in my index.html file, then how do I start my client.js file to make sure that I can use the socket.io-client API? I don't require it or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still an issue with the socket.io example code. I was able to figure it out. The issue is that the file-system works differently when running whatever server (including localhost).

In short, to resolve this issue, in `index.js` (or what is called `server.js` in OP's question), replace:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

with

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   
});
```

(of course feel free to fill the `app.get` function later if needed.